# d3.js forceSimulation() with zoom and drag (I can't add a text label with nodes' info)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

When I try to append a text to node something goes wrong and text doesn't show. What did I miss?
I'm new to d3.js and use version 4.

```
var container = svg.append("g")

var link = container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line");

var node = container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

node.append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name + ":";
    })

svg.call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoom));

function zoom() {
    container.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

This is a link to all the code: https://pastebin.com/rpL1btne

Here is a screenshot of browser...
[image]